# Trying to Charge Honda Fit 2015, Car's Headlights Flash Once Charging Starts

Tags: honda, battery, battery-charger, fit

I'm not a car person *at all*, so thanks in advance for any help!

My wife's 2015 Honda Fit hasn't been used for months (thanks to Corona). I'm trying to use a [Schumacher SC1307 6/12V Automatic Battery Charger and 30/85A Engine Starter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0756PG828), to charge the battery using a wall current, to get it running again.

I was able to hook everything up, but when I turned the charger on, the car started blinking the headlights every second.  Since I imagine it can't charge well while doing that, I turned it off ... but now I'm unsure how to charge the battery.

I saw something online that suggested I disconnect the battery first, but:

A) other sites don't mention anything about Honda Fits specifically needing to disconnect the battery to get a jump/charge

B) I don't know how to disconnect the battery

So my question is, do I need to disconnect the battery?  If not, how can I charge the car without disconnecting it, and if I do need to disconnect it ... how do I do that on a Honda Fit?

Comment: Just leave the charger on overnight. Battery is under the hood, disconnect the negative battery cable usually a 10mm wrench will get the job done.

Comment: So I do need to disconnect the battery, and to do that I just ... unbolt the thing attached to it?

Comment: Yes disconnect the battery, Be Sure it is the Negative Side! The reason headlight are flashing is the alarm is going off i think. Once battery is charged connect battery back, then use key fob to lock-unlock the doors, if no fob use the key to manually lock-unlock the drivers door.